# What is being braided in SL(2,Z)?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

[The braid group on 3 strands is a central extension of the modular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group#Relation_between_B3_and_the_modular_group).  By definition,
\[ B_3 = \langle \sigma_1, \sigma_2: \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1=\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2 \rangle \]
This group has a central element (commuting with both $\sigma1$ and $ \sigma_2$):
\[ \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2\]
The coset get mapped to elements of PSL(2,Z) (which can act on the hyperbolic plane).
\[ [\sigma_1] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right] \text{ and }
 [\sigma_2] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right] \]
I wonder, in terms of the hyperbolic plane, what is being braided here (modulo the garside elements).

Comment: If something were being braided, I'd think the relevant group would have a map to $B_3$, rather than from $B_3$.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20281/details-for-the-action-of-the-braid-group-b-3-on-modular-forms/20287#20287

Answer (score 8):

Without thinking about this too carefully:  I think what's getting braided are three of the Weierstrass points of an elliptic curve.  More precisely:  consider the space of distinct 3-tuples of points p,q,r on A^1.  On the one hand, you can braid these points around.  On the other hand, every path in this space (i.e. every braid) gives a family of elliptic curves

y^2 = (x-p)(x-q)(x-r)

and you can ask what the braid does to the homology of the elliptic curve; that's an element of SL_2(Z).

Comment: Don't you need some other identification between the homology of two elliptic curves in a family to get an element of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Otherwise you just get a homomorphism between two groups which are abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. 

Comment: @Qiaochu: That's what you get from the Gauss-Manin connection. 